# Error in initializing C# form with SQLite ADO.Net and error checking

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, ado.net

I am opening an SQLite database with a C# WinForm and trying to handle exceptions, and getting an odd error. I have implemented this code

```
bool TryingtoStart = true;

while (TryingtoSTart)
{
    try
        {
             dbc.Open();

                 departmentDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from DEPARTMENT", dbc);
                 // etc
        }

       catch (SQLiteException ex)
       {
              DialogResult r = MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this,  ex.Message.ToString(), "Database error", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel);

              if (r == DialogResult.Cancel) TryingtoStart = false;
       }

       catch (Exception exc)
       {
              DialogResult r = MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this,  exc.Message.ToString(), "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel);
              if (r == DialogResult.Cancel) TryingtoStart = false;
       }

       if (!TryingtoStart) Application.Exit();
}
```

And get the error

```
"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."
```

when run. That comes from the second catch() ie it's not an SQLException. If I remove my catchs, I get the error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Open()
```

with the line number of the open() call

If I remove the while loop *and* the try/catch, it all works fine. This code is in the Form_Load() method.

I have tried but cannot understand this. I've commented / uncommented a few times and the error is consistent.

Comment: doh! Thanks Zohar. Will a test like if(dbc.State == ConnectionState.Open) break; work OK? There seems to be a few states a connection can be in so looking specifically for Open seems safe

Comment: Check the code in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all goes well in the first attempt with no exception, you don't go out of the loop. This means you are running the `dbc.Open();` again - once it's already opened.
This is what's causing the exception.

BTW, data adapters implicitly opens the connection if it's closed, so you don't even need the `dbc.Open()` code line.

A better implementation of your code would be something like this:

```
bool TryingtoStart = true;

while (TryingtoSTart)
{

    using(var dbc = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
             using(var departmentDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from DEPARTMENT", dbc))
             {
                  // etc
             }

            // Note: This row will only be executed if there where no exceptions until this point in the code
            TryingtoStart = false;
        }

        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {

            if (MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this,  ex.Message.ToString(), "Database error", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel) == DialogResult.Cancel) Application.Exit();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            if (MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this,  exc.Message.ToString(), "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel) == DialogResult.Cancel) Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Note I'm creating both the `SQLiteConnection` and the `SQLiteDataAdapter` inside a `using` statement - because they both implement the `IDisposable` interface.